# NSTextField, NSNumberFormatter nil input validation and handling

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

In IB i inserted a configured `NSNumberFormatter` to the `NSTextField`, which validates users number input

All works fine, when i input a text or a number which is too large - i get the warning prompt

However, when the user deletes the value using back, the `NSNumberFormatter` raises for

```
[NSNull doubleValue]
```

as it gets the `NSNull` value

**How to configure the nil value handling for numbers?** I assigned the null placeholder, but this apparently doesn't stop the exception from happening

- the desired behavior is to don't validate nil and / or don't throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

1) Subclass `NSNumberFormatter`

2) Implement (will put a 0, if empty)

```
- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj {

    if (obj == nil) {
        return @"0";
    }

    return [super stringForObjectValue:obj];

}
```

3) set the class in IB